# search a line that contain a special character using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I wonder if there is a command in Linux that can help me to find a line that begins with "*" and contains the special character "|"
 for example

```
* Date       | Auteurs
```

Comment: i've updated the answer to print also the line numbers, tell me if it works as expected for you.

Comment: it's working thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
grep -ne '^\*.*|' "${filename}"
```

Or if you want to use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\*.*|/{=;p}' "${filename}" | sed '{N;s/\n/:/}'
```

Or (gnu) `awk` equivalent (require to backslash the pipe):

```
awk '/^\*.*\|/' "${filename}"
```

Where:

- `^` : start of the line
- `\*`: a literal `*`
- `.*`: zero or more generic char (not newline)
- `|` : a literal pipe

**NB**: `"${filename}"`: i've assumed you're using the command in a script with the target file passed in a double quoted variable as "${filename}". In the shell simply use the actual name of the file (or the path to it).

**UPDATE** *(line numbers)*

Modify the above commands to obtain also the line number of the matched lines. With `grep` is simple as to add `-n` switch:

```
grep -ne '^\*.*|' "${filename}"
```

We obtain an output like this:

```
81806:* Date       | Auteurs
```

To obtain exactly the same output from `sed` and `awk` we have to complicate the commands a little bit:

```
awk '/^\*.*\|/{print NR ":" $0}' "${filename}"
# the = print the line number, p the actual match but it's on two different lines so the second sed call
sed -n '/^\*.*|/{=;p}' "${filename}" | sed '{N;s/\n/:/}'
```